# dyanamically change the database name in SqlMapConfig.xml file

Tags: ibatis, sqlmap

I want to change the database name in SqlMapConfig.xml file from the application, does any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the database when you instantiate the Ibatis mapper instance; I do this for switching between debug and release builds of the application and hence accessing a different target database.

If your xml file is in an assembly called `DatalayerAssembly` for example, you might have a method for returning your new Ibatis instance based on a database name like this:

```cs
public IBatisNet.DataMapper.ISqlMapper CreateNewIbatis(
    String serverName,
    String databaseName)
{
    // Load the config file (embedded resource in assembly).
    System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = IBatisNet.Common.Utilities.Resources.GetEmbeddedResourceAsXmlDocument("SqlMapConfig.xml, DatalayerAssembly");

    // Overwrite the connectionString in the XmlDocument, hence changing database.
    // NB if your connection string needs extra parameters,
    // such as `Integrated Security=SSPI;` for user authentication,
    // then append that to InnerText too.
    xmlDoc["sqlMapConfig"]["database"]["dataSource"]
        .Attributes["connectionString"]
        .InnerText = "Server=" + serverName + ";Database=" + databaseName;

    // Instantiate Ibatis mapper using the XmlDocument via a Builder,
    // instead of Ibatis using the config file.
    IBatisNet.DataMapper.Configuration.DomSqlMapBuilder builder = new IBatisNet.DataMapper.Configuration.DomSqlMapBuilder();
    IBatisNet.DataMapper.ISqlMapper ibatisInstance = builder.Configure(xmlDoc);

    // Now use the ISqlMapper instance ("ibatisInstance") as normal.
    return ibatisInstance;
}
```

I'm using this approach in Ibatis 1.6.2.0 on .Net but the exact SqlMap config file might vary depending by version. Either way the approach is the same; you just might need a different Xml path (i.e. the bit that reads `["sqlMapConfig"]["database"]` etc may need changing for your config file)

Hope that helps.